# How can i convert a MS Word 2003 document into HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'd like to extract the content of a MS Word 2003 document into HTML in C#.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest way to do it

http://asptutorials.net/C-SHARP/convert-ms-word-docs-to-html/

They key point in the article is that they use the SaveAs function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220734.aspx

Like this:

```
    string newfilename = folder_to_save_in + FileUpload1.FileName.Replace(".doc", ".html");
    object o_nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;    
    object o_newfilename = newfilename;
    object o_format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;
    object o_encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
    object o_endings = Word.WdLineEndingType.wdCRLF;
    // SaveAs requires lots of parameters, but we can leave most of them empty:
    wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref o_newfilename, ref o_format, ref o_nullobject,
    ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject,
    ref o_nullobject, ref o_nullobject, ref o_encoding, ref o_nullobject,
    ref o_nullobject, ref o_endings, ref o_nullobject);
```

The library is
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

If I remember correctly Word is required on the machine where the code is executed. If it's ASP.NET it is required on the server.

Comment: I think you forgot to assign/declare o_nullobject in your sample. It should be set to `System.Type.Missing`

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:
1. save as HTML, as described by napster
2. transform the Open XML to HTML; the XSLT is available at http://www.codeplex.com/OpenXMLViewer
3. for the cleanest HTML, write code to convert each style in the document to CSS, and put any direct formatting in @style.

Is Word installed on the computer running your C# code?

Comment: Word is installed on the computer, it's not an issue.
With napster's solution, I got some realy messy html output. I'm sure someone has allready written all the code to clean that html?